# nginx - Rate limit for each individual url

Tags: nginx, rate-limiting, nginx-config

I am having a issue where I am trying to set a rate limit for each individual URL in a single location block such as "location / { }"

```
limit_req_zone $request_uri zone=one:10m rate=6r/m;



location / {
    proxy_pass http://app:8000;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    limit_req zone=one;
}
```

In the end the url "/example/1" can have 5 requests per second sent while "/example/2" can have another 5 requests per second sent.